# Which will load faster in the browser: including images in HTML as DataURLs, or using the normal img tag with src url?

Tags: php, css, html, data-url

We're generating our pages in PHP and want to make the generated pages load as quickly as possible in the browser. When generating the pages (which are `.html` pages) we realized we have two options:

**Page with data URL images**

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah1" />
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah2" />
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah3" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Page with "normal" images**

```
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="/images/image1.png" />
        <img src="/images/image2.png" />
        <img src="/images/image3.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

There are pros/cons of the DataURL:

Pros:

- Fewer trips from browser to server *(there would only be ONE trip)* - Given the generated nature, and needing to maintain this and the CSS, using sprites does not work well on this project
- Less bandwidth usage on smaller images
- Much faster in HTTPS

Cons:

- Image sizes will be larger due to base64 encoding (about 37% larger)
- Doesn't work in IE7 and in IE8, there's a limit on size of 32KB

Will the "one-trip" really make a big difference? Will it be noticeable to the user?

Comment: @SLaks OK, on what? :)

Comment: separate images will "feel" faster for the user. and would be faster if the images where cached

Comment: Use a CDN like CloudFront?

Comment: @Orangepill Are you sure they'd feel faster? Doesn't that depend on how long it takes the browser to make the trips? I believe most browsers also put a limit on the number of concurrent connections allowed within one tab.

Comment: Another thing to remember is by base64 encoding your images are going to gain about a 1/3 of their weight again.

Comment: @Orangepill Yes, I mention that in my post. :) But that doesn't mean it's slower. Multiple trips is usually slower.

Comment: I think you would have to be loading a lot of small images that would have a short cache lifespan for it to be a better performing solution... And I would argue if you are loading a bunch of small images you would be better served by using an image sprite.

Comment: I think the technique would work good for structural site elements if embedded in an external style sheets. That way it won't exclude it from being cached by the browser.